# A good substitute for "developed a disease"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

The words *contracting* or *catching* a disease mainly refers to the communicable ones.

If the disease/condition is a slowly developing one, then what would be a good substitute for "developed?"

> During the fall of last year, he developed ulcers.

Comment: What's wrong with *developed*?

Comment: If the disease is a slowly-developing one then "developed" is probably about the best choice.  "came down with" is a common informal term for taking ill with something, but probably implies a more rapid progression.

Comment: Develop describes the idea best, but I have overused it in my piece and need some other word.

Comment: You could paraphrase: '... began to suffer from ...' etc.

Comment: "Fell ill with".

Comment: An expression that is widely used, which I happen to loathe and never use myself, is,  'he was diagnosed with beriberi'. It seems to place responsibility for the condition on the shoulders of the doctor, as if everything would have been alright if only the wretched doctor hadn't interfered.

Comment: Any other choice is leading to either magnify the suffering or make it appear too fast. I use diagnosis later in the piece so can't talk about it when the disease "develops."

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you have exhausted the thesaurus, it usually means you should try to rewrite the sentence. It isn't a matter of finding another word. That said, how about:
acquired?   showed signs/symptoms of...? suffered?   symptomatic of?? manifest? indicate? indications?

Answer (score 1):

It's funny, but in the US, even if something is not communicable, I guess we often use a phrase that implies causation:

"She's got cancer."
"He ended up getting ulcers"
"When she got Alzheimer's, they put her in a home"

Comment: Forgive me, but I am not clear about how any of those 'imply causation'. How would one say it in a way that didn't 'imply causation'?

Comment: Sorry... I guess that wasn't the best way to put it. In other words: To "get" something implies action - rather  than if the thing manifested of its own accord.

Comment: I think by causation oldbag was referring to the sense of action on someone's part that's implicit in the word "got."

Answer (score 1):

In a medical environment, "developed" would fit most signs and symptoms.  It wouldn't sound natural to use it for certain diseases, though. e.g. When discussing a case, we wouldn't say:

> "This patient developed a myocardial infarction." An MD or RN will just say "he has an acute M.I." or "he had an acute M.I.", and will save "develop" for complications: "this patient with acute M.I. developed third-degree heart block, ventricular tachycardia or pulmonary edema".

The layman, on the other hand, will surely use "has", "had", "has got", "had got". We don't hear people say "I've contracted or developed a cold"

Comment: This was useful to the discussion.